# How to get the first match from text using regex in vb.net

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a RegEx I am using in vb.net and i can get all the matches of the text but i want to get the first match of the text, this is what i am using.

Text: `:1283 xxxxxxxxxx :1288 :9879`

RegEx: `:[0-9]+`

How do i just get the first match (`:1283`)?

The code i am using is:

```
Dim MRIDRegex As New Regex(":[0-9]+")
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim mrid As String = String.Empty
    For Each item As Match In MRIDRegex.Matches(message)

        count += 1
        If count = 1 Then
            mrid = item.Value
        End If

    Next
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you tried?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand im using an online vb.net regex tester

Comment: people need to explain why they are down voting this question???????

Comment: I down voted it because it didn't show research effort.  A quick web-search could find the information you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched on Google for [vb.net regex match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet), and this was [the first result](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet).  This is the code sample they used.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
    ' The input string.
    Dim value As String = "/content/alternate-1.aspx"

    ' Invoke the Match method.
    Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(value, _
                     "content/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.aspx$", _
                     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    ' If successful, write the group.
    If (m.Success) Then
        Dim key As String = m.Groups(1).Value
        Console.WriteLine(key)
    End If
    End Sub

End Module
```